# How can I prove or disprove that the set of roots of the trigonometric polynomials with integer coefficients is denumerable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, polynomials, cardinals

How can I prove that the set of  roots of the **trigonometric polynomials** WITH integer coefficients is denumerable ? The concept of **trigonometric polynomials** is also not clear to me.

I know how to show the roots of the polynomials in one variable with rational coefficients are denumerable.

Can anyone please help me to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigonometric polynomial is a polynomial of the form $$W(x)=a_0 +\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k \cos kx +b_k \sin kx)$$
If we substitute $$\cos kx =\frac{e^{ikx} +e^{-ikx}}{2} \mbox{   } \sin kx =\frac{e^{ikx} -e^{-ikx}}{2i}$$ where $i^2 =-1.$

And then $z=e^{ix}$ then the equation $$W(x) =0$$ is equivalent to some equation $$P(z) =\sum_{l=0}^{2n} c_l z^l =0$$
But from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra the equation $$P(z)=0$$ has at most $2n$ solutions say $\{z_1, z_2, z_3,....z_{2n}\}$
and each equation $$\cos x =\frac{z_s +\overline{z_s }}{2} \mbox{   } \sin x =\frac{z_s -\overline{z_s}}{2i}$$ has atm most countable solutions for $s=1,2,...,2n.$

Therefore the set $$\{ x:W(x) =0\}$$ is countable as finite union of countable sets.

Comment: No, it is the countable union of countable sets.  This is critical if you work in $ZF$ instead of $ZFC.\ \ ZF$ cannot prove that the countable union of countable sets is countable, but $ZFC$ can.